# How to get the params of AJAX-query on the server-side in CodeIgniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have the AJAX-code, which calls to controller of CodeIgniter's back-end:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#select_bank").change(function(){
                selected_bank = $("#select_bank option:selected").text();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'<?=base_url().'atm/select_region/&'+selected_bank; ?>',
                    success:function(msg){

                    }
                });

            });

    });
```

So, I want to get this params in the controller (CodeIgniter), but, because of this is not at the any form, using the

```
$bank = $this->input->post('')
```

gives no effect. really, I'd like to clarify this moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the ajax function that you're sending POST data

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'html',
                url: <?= base_url ?> + "atm/select_region",
                data: {nameofpostvariable:valuethatyousend},
                success: function(output){

                },
                error: function(output){                
                    alert('error');                         
                }               
            });
```

On the line `data: {nameofpostvariable:valuethatyousend},` you are creating a $_POST['nameofpostvariable']